# how to establish a phone call remotely via ubuntu?

Tags: modem, remote, phone

I'd like to be able to establish a phone call in this procedure ,

1. tunnel my voice from PC called `a` to PC called `b`
2. `b` had modem with `phone line` connected

so how to establish phone call remotely  ?

Both pc has ubuntu installed

can ubuntu do this task

Answer (score 1):

yes ubuntu can do this task. I'm sure there are several applications that will allow you to make "calls" to another computer.

My personal favorite is sflphone its an ip telephone client.
It has an ip to ip call function wich does exactly what you want.

It also allows you to call to real telephones if you get an account at some local ip telephone provider and configure your sflphone to use it.

http://sflphone.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is more asking about proxying phonecalls, not making calls from a computer.  The answer is yes.  Asterisk is an open source PBX that can proxy SIP communications over POTS.

Comment: What do you mean by `proxy SIP communications over POTS`. Can you please elaborate.